# new to java - relationship between new String() and weakHashMap

Tags: java

I have been going through [the following tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_weakhashmap_class.htm) , and I came across this code :

```
map.put(new String("Maine"), "Augusta");
```

just to experiment, I changed it to:

```
String hold = "Maine";
map.put(hold, "Augusta");
```

As a result, the loop goes on forever meaning that this object does not get garbage collected as it should, because we are using WeakHashMap. I have no idea why this is. What makes new String() different from String hold in this situation ?

also.. there is one more question - why does this map have to be static or else containKeys will give an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the link you posted:

> allows a key-value pair to be garbagecollected **when its key is no
>   longer referenced outside of the WeakHashMap**

So in first example, `"Maine"` string is not externally referenced by anything, so it will be garbage-collected eventually (when GC runs). In the second example, it is referenced from outside the `WeakHashMap` (by `hold`) and thus it is not garbage-collected.

Comment: got it , thanks, how ever there is one more question - why does this map have to be static or else containKeys will give an error ?

Comment: @m0skit0 to be totally correct, you should say that `"Maine"` is _eventually_ garbage collected. It does not have to be the case that this happens right away. It even may not happen at all.

Comment: @gexicide It will happen when GC runs, which is when it is garbage-collected. Let's try to not be too pedantic ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the String hold, you are making a strong reference, this means that "Maine" should not be garbage collected because some variable outside the weakmap references that String.

On the initial example, the only reference to "Maine" was inside the weakmap so this reference is called "weak". The variable is then garbage collected

Comment: got it , thanks, how ever there is one more question - why does this map have to be static or else containKeys will give an error ?

Comment: Because you are executing the code in a static method, so non-static objects cannot be accessed, if you want it to be non-static you should create a new entity of WeakHashMap. and access the map through this new object.